# Can't update web properties account id through the Management API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm unable to update the web properties account id through the Analytics Management API.

It returns response 200 but without any changes.

I'm able to update other properties like the name or the website url.

The account to which I want to move the web property is part of the same google account. So, I don't see why it wouldn't let update the account.

Are there some conditions when moving web properties ?

I also tested the request with the live debugger in the Analytics documentation reference and I get the same response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of the fields on the web [property resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#resource) are writeable.  You can not change the account id on a web property.

I will contact the team about getting a note added to the documentation so that you can see which fields are writable.

> Are there some conditions when moving web properties ?

It is not possible to move a web property.